# Page redirected and displays "URL No Longer Exists" in a webservice callout from Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, callout

There is no issue when the callout to a SAP webservice returns records less than 3k. But if it exceeds i got "URL No Longer Exists" error. Actually this error is not displaying in the current page where i am initiating the webservice call and display the results.

When i initiate the callout by the click of a button on the vf page, it takes a while to get the response. But after 2 to 3 minutes suddenly the page is redirected and took me to a page where i am getting the above error and the URL of the page is different from the page where i actually there.

> https://cs7.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=066M00000005Igz&ic=1

I checked the debug log but it displays "Maximum log size reached".

Any suggestions why i am getting "URL No Longer Exists" error?

[image]

**Update:**

After marking several adjustments to the log filters, i am able to see the summary but not the exception.

```
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 1000000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 0
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 0
  Maximum CPU time: 11938 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 1 out of 10
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 0
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

Comment: Did you apply log filters to narrow down to only the useful info ? That might provide more insight.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelDeRycke. I am changing the log filters now. I'll get back to you with more details.

Comment: Keep in mind that the total of callout time for a single execution context is limited to 2 minutes, so be sure your SAP is able to respond within that timeframe, else you'll need an async integration. Though that should give a clear governor limit error message.

Comment: I checked and the response time is 30 to 50 seconds. Actually the error should be in handling the response. Is the exceed in view state size would result in such URL No Longer Exists error?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke, i've updated the post with debug log summary. But I did not find any exception. What could be wrong? - Thanks.